# $X\in L^1$, then $\int_{|X|>n}XdP\to 0$ and $P(A_n)\to 0 \Rightarrow \int_{A_n}XdP\to 0$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I'm trying to prove the following:

**1. Suppose $X\in L^1$, then  $\int_{|X|>n}XdP\to 0$**

Attempt:

$$\int_{\Omega}|X|dP = \int_{|X|≤n}|X|dP+ \int_{|X|>n}|X|dP = M<\infty \space \forall n$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_n \int_{|X|≤n}|X|dP + \lim_n \int_{|X|>n}|X|dP =M \Rightarrow \lim_n \int_{\Omega}|X|1_{|X_n|≤n}dP + \lim_n \int_{\Omega}|X|1_{|X_n|>n}dP$$

$\lim_n |X|1_{|X|≤n}\to |X|$ monotonically since $|X|1_{|X|≤n}≤|X|1_{|X|≤n+1} \space \forall n$

Therefore, by MCT, $$\lim_n \int_{\Omega}|X|1_{|X_n|≤n}dP = \int_{\Omega}\lim_n|X|1_{|X_n|≤n}dP \to \int_{\Omega}|X|dP =M$$

so, $$\int_{|X|≤n}|X|dP+ \int_{|X|>n}|X|dP \to \int_{\Omega}|X|dP + \lim_N \int_{|X|>n}|X|dP =\int_{\Omega}|X|dP$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_N |\int_{|X|>n}XdP|<\lim_N \int_{|X|>n}|X|dP \to 0$$

Is this approach correct? what's it missing? If so, is there an easier way?

Second:

**2. Let $A,A_n$ be events, if $P(A_n) \to 0$ then $\int_{A_n}XdP \to 0$**

Attempt:

$$\int_{A_n}|X|dP= \int_{A_n\cap|X|≤M}|X|dP + \int_{A_n\cap|X|>M}|X|dP≤MP(A_n) + \int_{A_n\cap|X|>M}|X|dP$$

$$\to 0 + \int_{A_n\cap|X|>M}|X|dP \to 0 \space \text{ when } n,M\to\infty$$

Is the above split/strategy justified?

Thanks!

Comment: The conclusion of the question of part 1 does not involve $A$ or $A_n$, so why do you mention them in the assumption?

Comment: They're for part 2, I can edit the question if that'd make everyone feel better— and it's fixed

Comment: In the second part, what does $A$ have to do with $\int_{A_n} X\, dP$?

Comment: I copied the question from my book, it's not entirely clear, but I believe it to mean $A_n\to A$ and $P(A_n)\to P(A) =0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Well, your argumentation looks rather complicated to me. It is easier to prove it like this:

   Since $1_{\{|X|>n\}} |X| \, \to 1_{\{|X|=\infty\}} \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ and $|1_{\{|X|>n\}}|X|| \leq |X| \in L^1$, it follows from the dominated convergence theorem that
   $$\int_{\{|X|>n\}} |X| \, d\mathbb{P} \to \int_{\{|X||=\infty\}} |X| \, d\mathbb{P}=0. \tag{1}$$
   As $\left| \int_{\{|X| >n\}} X \, d\mathbb{P} \right| \leq \int_{\{|X|>n\}} |X| \, d\mathbb{P}$, the claim follows. (Note: In $(1)$ we have used that $\mathbb{P}(|X|=\infty)=0$; just suppose that $\mathbb{P}(|X|=\infty)>0$, then $$\int |X| \, d\mathbb{P} \geq \int_{\{|X|=\infty\}} |X| \, d\mathbb{P}=\infty,$$ in contradiction to our assumption $X \in L^1$.)
2. The idea of your proof is correct. However, you have to estimate
   $$M \mathbb{P}(A_n) + \int_{A_n \cap \{|X|>M\}} |X| \, \, d\mathbb{P}$$
   from above by
   $$M \mathbb{P}(A_n) + \int_{\{|X|>M\}} |X| \, d\mathbb{P}$$
   *before* letting $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks! 1. is a lot cleaner. appreciate it.

Comment: @user237393 You are welcome.